# Replica Set Connection Issue - MongoDB WritableServerSelector

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have an annoying problem with the java driver connecting to a replica set in the remote environment.

I am using the below code to connect to the server through Mongo DB Java Async API 3.2.2.

```
  MongoClient mongoClusterClient = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                .clusterSettings(ClusterSettings.builder()
                                      .applyConnectionString(hrvuConnectionString)
                                                                                .serverSelectionTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                                               .build())
                                      .connectionPoolSettings(ConnectionPoolSettings.builder()
                                                    .applyConnectionString(hrvuConnectionString)
                                                    .build())
                                                    .serverSettings(ServerSettings.builder().build())
                                                    .credentialList(getMongoConnectionString().getCredentialList())
                                                    .sslSettings(SslSettings.builder()
                                                        .applyConnectionString(hrvuConnectionString)
                                                        .build())
                                                        .socketSettings(SocketSettings.builder()
                                                            .applyConnectionString(hrvuConnectionString)
                                                            .build())
                                                            .build());
  return mongoClusterClient;
```

My connection string takes the below format.

```
mongodb://node-a.singlenode-mongodb.qa.shared.eu.qa.aws.app.io:27017,node-b.singlenode-mongodb.qa.shared.eu.qa.aws.app.io:27017,node-c.singlenode-mongodb.qa.shared.eu.qa.aws.app.io:27017/?replicaSet=rst-app-shared-qa&w=0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&maxPoolSize=30&minpoolsize=5&maxidletimems=60000
```

I tried with different options in the client creation (supplying hosts instead of the connection string for the ClusterSettings) but always ended up with the below problem:

```
2016-07-14 06:54:28.797 [I] [                                ] [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] | No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=node-a.singlenode-mongodb.qa.shared.eu.qa.aws.app.io:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=node-b.singlenode-mongodb.qa.shared.eu.qa.aws.app.io:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=node-c.singlenode-mongodb.qa.shared.eu.qa.aws.app.io:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

What is more interesting is after reporting this, the application is obtaining the connections independently. And there is no problem with the single DB server that is installed in my local environment. Application is functioning as expected in the local setup.

I see that it needs to get the primary node for db writes (node-a.singlenode-mongodb.qa.shared.eu.qa.aws.app.io in this case).

Is there a way to tell the driver about the primary node while connecting? I am stuck with this error for the last 3 days and any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Chandra.

Comment: Removed the new WritableServerSelector code and edited the question accordingly. Whatever be the case, we are getting the same error all the times.

Comment: Does just passing the connection string to `MongoClients.create` work?

Comment: > Is there a way to tell the driver about the primary node while connecting?
No as replicaset topology can change the driver determines the replicaset topology and the primary itself.

Comment: Sorry for a delayed response on SOF. There was a problem with the version we were using. It is actually fixed now with the updated versions. Follow this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2269